# How Does Firebug Get Contents From an IFrame?

Tags: firefox, dom, iframe, firebug

I am well aware of cross-origin restrictions when it comes to browsers, but what I don't get is how Firebug can get and display the HTML from an iframe with this restriction in place. Is there something plugins have access to that lets it get around this?

Comment: As mah said, there are few such safety restrictions on add-ons.  That's why it's imperative you only install add-ons you trust, as they can do anything to your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins have access to quite a bit. They're not considered cross-origin, they're considered a part of your browser.